# What is the procedure to switch app from one developer account to another developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, account

Hi I am currently using a individual developer account to submit my app to the app store. My current version in the store is already at 1.7.

However now, I want to switch using my company account to submit the same app.

What is the procedure in doing so? Do I need to remove the current version from the app store? Also do I need to reset my version of the app to 1.0?

Comment: This would be better asked on the apple developer forums.

Comment: Last time I looked into this, it isn't possible. Basically you can't transfer an app-id to another account. You may need to contact Apple to see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the ownership of an app to another developer without removing the app from the store. The app retains its reviews and ratings during and after the transfer, and users continue to have access to future updates. There’s no limit to the number of apps you can transfer, but each app needs to be transferred individually.

All transfers and deletions are performed by the team agent. To learn more about a team agent’s function.

[Here is step by step explanation on Apple's Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)